# taking pictures and uploading them to parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I tried using the parse.com tutorial but was not useful to me as it uses the entire view controller. I need to upload multiple photos that have just been taken along with multiple text fields that are on that page.

Any help is appreciated. If you can get the parse tutorial to work in storyboard with more that one picture and also have text fields save that is probably the easiest way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sample code from this [LINK](https://parse.com/tutorials/saving-images).

```
// Convert to JPEG with 50% quality
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.5f);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:data];

// Save the image to Parse

[imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The image has now been uploaded to Parse. Associate it with a new object 
        PFObject* newPhotoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"PhotoObject"];
        [newPhotoObject setObject:imageFile forKey:@"image"];

        [newPhotoObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Saved");
            }
            else{
                // Error
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: I will try this but the tutorial that you have linked has not been working with my project after I converted it to a .storyboard.

Comment: i think the problem with the passing image to other view controller.

Comment: I understand but what I need to do is have a small field that the user can tap. Then they can take a picture and then write about it in a text field. It will all be saved in one line in the class.